# signal.signal receives sigint/sigterm when child process ends

Tags: python, process, signals

I have the following simplified example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging, logging.handlers
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time, sys, signal

def child_proc(sleepr):

    print 'Child: Started child, waiting'
    time.sleep(sleepr)
    print 'Child: Ended sleep, exiting' 

def cleanup(a, b):
    print 'Main: Got SIGTERM: ' + str(a) + ' : ' + str(b)

print 'Main: Starting process'
child_proc_th = Process(target=child_proc, args=(3,))
child_proc_th.start()

print 'Main: Pausing main thread'
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup)
signal.pause()

print 'Main: Running again after pause'
```

Why does the signal.pause resume once the child_proc has finished? I only want it to resume if a sigterm is received... Is child_proc sending its exit signal up the stack to the parent process? Or is there another way to do this...?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`signal.pause()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.pause) blocks until any signal is received. When a child exits it sends [`SIGCHLD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) to the parent. This causes `signal.pause()` to return.

As far as I can tell to achieve what you want you have to `signal.pause()` in a loop until the correct signal is received.

Something like this:

```
sigtermreceived = False

def sigterm(signum, frame):
  global sigtermreceived
  sigtermreceived = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm)

while not sigtermreceived:
  signal.pause()
```

Note that there is also [`Process.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join):

```
child_proc_th = Process(target=child_proc, args=(3,))
child_proc_th.start()
child_proc_th.join()
```

This will block until the child process exits. Which is basically the behaviour you have now but without messing with signals.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, what relevance does the signal.SIGTERM have if it doesn't only look for the correct signal (in this instance SIGTERM)...?
Looking at SIGCHLD now...

Comment: you seem to have a misunderstanding about how signals work. signals happen whether you installed a custom handler or not. signals are part of the system. python just offers an interface to handle them. read the wikipedia article for more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

Comment: I believe that is what he's described here... Basically just making sure with a handler that the correct signal has been caught, if not 're-pause'. No?

Comment: FYI, this solved my problem thanks. I didn't realise that the signal.pause would trigger on ANY signal being received, and the handler would only fire if the stated signal was caught.

Comment: FYI, this solved my problem thanks. I didn't realise that the signal.pause would trigger on ANY signal being received, and the handler would only fire if the stated signal was caught.